# How to make that useEffect run only one time when dom render in Nextjs or can u suggest some better way

Tags: react-hooks, next.js

I am calling a function in a lib folder that fetches data from the server but this `useEffect` is being called twice; therefore, it is affecting the output. How do you solve this issue in Nextjs? I see some info but that is for React. If anyone has any idea to solve it, that would be very helpful to me. Thank You......

```js
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import nookies from "nookies";
import { userDetails } from "../../libs/chats";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Index from "./index";
const friends = ({ token }: any) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleLogout = () => {
    const init = async () => {
      const data = await axios.post("/api/auth/logout");
      if (data.status === 200) {
        router.push("/?login");
      }
    };
    init();
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const getFriends = async () => {
      const { data } = await userDetails(token);
      if (!data.username) {
        prompt("Enter a name : ");
      }
    };
    if (!token) {
      router.push("/?login");
      return;
    }
    getFriends();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Index>
      <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
    </Index>
  );
};

export default friends;

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx: any) => {
  const cookies = nookies.get(ctx);
  const token = cookies.token;
  return {
    props: {
      token: token || null,
    },
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the `token` object in the dependency array in the useEffect. This should cause the useEffect to only run when the token changes:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
 const getFriends = async () => {
   const { data } = await userDetails(token);
  if (!data.username) {
    prompt("Enter a name : ");
  }
 };
   if (!token) {
  router.push("/?login");
  return;
}
  getFriends();
 }, [token]);
```